# how do i target divs to make them invisible during click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code example: http://codepen.io/asuh/pen/JgdLK

This is for a responsive design I'm working on. The amount of columns will change depending on my breakpoints and width of the divs at this breakpoints

When you click on any of the divs, the hidden content appears in an absolutely positioned div relative to its parent. It functions as a drop down full of links.

In this example, what I need to do is target the container(s) below the active drop down and make that or those containers fade out or invisible. Currently, you can see the container box shadows showing through the edges of the drop down and I'd prefer for them to just be completely or mostly invisible.

Here's the JS:

```
$('.module article').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.module-content').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest('section').find('article');
  $('.module article').not($this).slideUp();
  $this.slideToggle('slow').addClass('active');
});
```

I keep trying something like this but it doesn't work:

```
if($('.module article').hasClass('active')) {
     $('.module:nth-child(3)').fadeTo('fast',0);
}
```

How do I modify the above to make it work? Or am I approaching it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the `.module-content`-elements .
All elements with a `offset().left` equal to the clicked element's `offset().left` , and a `offset().top` higher than the `offset().top` of the clicked element are placed underneath the clicked element.

```
    $('.module-content').click(function() {
  var offset=$(this).offset();
   var $this = $(this).closest('section').find('article');
  $('.module article').not($this).slideUp();
  $('.module-content').parent().css('visibility','visible');
  if($this.is(':hidden'))
  {$('.module-content')
    .filter(function(){return ($(this).offset().left==offset.left 
                                && $(this).offset().top>offset.top);})
      .parent().css('visibility','hidden');}

  $this.slideToggle('slow').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: @dr-molle Oh, this looks great! Except, when you close the same div right away, the containers which disappeared don't reappear. Is there a way to reverse the visibility:hidden when you close the div?

Comment: See the updated code. It now hides the elements below only when the article is hidden.